# How to configure embedded jetty 9 to reload static content dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded jetty 9 with Spring MVC and my html didn't reload after changes. It's my config :

```
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setResourceBase("resources");
webAppContext.setContextPath("/spring-social-quickstart/");
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(webAppContext);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Comment: Are you sure that Jetty is serving the static content?  It might seem strange, but many 3rd party frameworks take this responsibility over (spring, jersey, etc)

Comment: Yes, cause jetty has Resource Handlers but I am not sure about reloading

Comment: Actually... assuming no 3rd party handling of resources, your example would use the `DefaultServlet` (not a `ResourceHandler`) to serve static resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried ResourceHandler but it didn't help me. Finally I've figured out that I can do it with IDE just by updating target folder

Comment: For the record, you can't mix `ResourceHandler` with a `WebAppContext`.  In fact, if you have a `ServletContextHandler` or `ContextHandler` in your handler tree, you can't use a `ResourceHandler` either.  Pretty much any scenario where you have a `ServletContext` a `ResourceHandler` is invalid.  (in all of those scenarios the recommended approach is to use a `DefaultServlet`)

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for help, Joakim!